# Кодировка в dbf-файлах КЛАДР

Tags: python, dbf, кладр

У меня есть коды [КЛАДР](https://www.gnivc.ru/inf_provision/classifiers_reference/kladr/), которые нужно превратить в географические координаты. Я пытаюсь прочитать базу данных КЛАДР в Python  c помощью библиотеки [dbf](https://pythonhosted.org/dbf/).

```
import dbf
table = dbf.Table('KLADR.dbf')
table.open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)
for record in table:
    print(record[0])
```

У меня возникает

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Не могу понять из документации, какую кодировку нужно использовать.

Помогите, пожалуйста?

Comment: Если работаете на Винде, то такая ошибка бывает при выводе в консоль юникода. Попробуйте в файл, также в среде, например PyCharm, ошибки не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DBF (dBase)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBF) - устаревший формат хранения файлов БД, который был достаточно популярен в эпоху `MS DOS`. В `MS DOS` использовалась [кодировка `CP866`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP866) для руccкого/украинского/белорусского языков.

```
table = dbf.Table(r'KLADR.dbf', codepage='cp866')
#   NOTE:                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Пример:

```
In [20]: for record in table[:10]:
    ...:     print(record[0])
    ...:
    ...:
Адыгея
Майкоп
Веселый
Гавердовский
Подгорный
Родниковый
Северный
Ханская
Западный
Косинов
```